# Iam not able to display the ppt infact i want to display not only ppt but also doc/ppt/pdf/xls files in a view..... in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

```
final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

if(list.size() > 0)

startActivity(context, intent);`
```

As you look at the above the code is to display a MS ppt on my android tablet.

Now my code procedure is as follows.

1.I will download a ppt from a URL and store it in sdcard .

2.Then i would like to display the ppt in a view which i duno wich exactly is suitable for this.

So Iam not able to display the ppt infact i want to display not only ppt but also doc/ppt/pdf/xls files in a view.....

So how to do it ?????

Comment: which version ur using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Hi friend I fased Same problem 
    that time instead of specifing we can pick suitable application from list of Application , 
    but below code is for example purpose only , not for 100% gurantee 
    depends on Requirement you have to change .



In ICS You have default polaris application you can use 


         else if (TEXT == type) {
                    File targetFile = new File(path);
                    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "text/plain");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, TEXT);
                } else if (type == DOC) {
                    File targetFile = new File(path);
                    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, DOC);
                } else if (type == EXCEL) {
                    File targetFile = new File(path);
                    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, EXCEL);
                } else {
                    File targetFile = new File(path);
                    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Webview for this . it worked for me .

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.WebView01);
String pdfurl = ""; // Url of pdf or doc file.

String weblink="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+pdfurl;    
mWebView.loadUrl(weblink);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro ,Hey i have another question, Lets assume i open a doc file using the webview as u suggstd and i have kingsoft office will that software help me in opening & saving the same doc page????

Comment: if you want to open your document using kingsoft office means you have to pass the package name in that intent.. then you file will get open using that software.